# web scraping of website in python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

On the below mentioned website, When I select date as 27 jun-2017 and Series/Run rates as "USD RATES 1100". After submitting it, rates opens below on that page. Till this point I am able to do it programitically. But I need 10 year rate(answer is 2.17) of above mentioned date and rate combination. Can some one please tell me what error I am making in the last line of the code.

https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\vick\Desktop\python_1\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180")
try: 
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/
   div[2]/button').click()
except:
      pass

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/a/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/div/ul/li[5]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').send_keys("27-Jul-
2017") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selectForm"]/input').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)/2;")
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-
content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Error I am getting in last line:
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="report-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]"}

Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait a second or two when you click the input field. Like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\vick\Desktop\python_1\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/180")
try: 
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
except:
      pass

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/a/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seriesNameAndRunCode_chosen"]/div/ul/li[5]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportDate"]').send_keys("27-Jul-2017") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selectForm"]/input').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)/2;")
time.sleep(2) #here is the part where you should wait. 
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Option B is to wait until the element has been loaded:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

....
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)/2;")
timeout = 5
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'report-content'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
......
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

In the first case Python waits 2 seconds and than continues. 
In the second case the Webdriver waits until the element is loaded (for maximal 5 seconds)

Tried the code and it works. Hope that helped.

Comment: @ads always glad to help, if the answer is correct please remember to select it ;)

Comment: I tried upvoting the answer. But it is saying" Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @ads https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/#answer-5235. Yeah you will have this 15 Points fast, you could try to answer some easy questions, next time when someone has a problem like this copy the code and try to make it work and post it ;-)

Comment: @ads you should still be able to mark the question as best answer by clicking the hollow check mark under the down vote